# Партнерка для сайта

Tags: phpmyadmin, php

Добра всем!

Подскажите логику, **как сделать партнерку для сайта** многоуровневую?
Один уровень понятно и с реализацией, и с проверкой, и запись в базу.

**А вот многоуровневая как?** Допустим, три уровня.

Спасибо!

Comment: Как же выборку делать допустим третьего уровня?

Comment: В каком случае у одного пользователя будет все три уровня?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, у вас есть таблица с полями:

```
id partner level code

id=1, partner = 0, level  = 1 
...
id=12, partner = 0, level  = 1 - партнеры первого уровня
id=13, partner = 12, level = 2 - партнер второго уровня. перешел по ссылке от ID=12
...
id=16, partner = 11, level = 2 - партнер второго уровня. перешел по ссылке от ID=11
id=17, partner = 16, level = 3 - партнер третьего уровня. перешел по ссылке от ID=16
```

`code` - уникальный код реферальной ссылки.
Для добавления нового, вам нужно получить реферальный код из GET или POST и вписать в базу:

```
$code = $_GET['referal'];   //получили код из реферальной ссылки
$r = mysql_query("select `id`,`level` from `base_name` where `code` = '$code'");
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($r); // узнали, данные владельца кода
$partner = $data['id'];    // запомним от кого мы пришли
$level = $data['level']+1; // изменим уровень реферала
$code = generate_new_code();//какая-то функция генерации
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `base_name` (`partner`,`level`,`code`) VALUES ('$partner','$level','$code')");
```

Comment: Да, неплохо.

Comment: Спасибо!

$code = generate_new_code();//какая-то функция генерации
-------
Смысл? Зачем?

Comment: У меня другой код рефки ))
Как же выборку делать допустим третьего уровня?

Comment: ну я же не знаю, как у вас код генерируется. вписал что-то, чтобы было.

выборка третьего уровня:
``$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `base_name WHERE `level` = '3'");``

Comment: В каком случае у одного пользователя будет все три уровня?

Comment: теоретически - никогда. практически, может, если он сам перейдет по своей ссылке. но это уже решается отдельно.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте деревья. В данном случае, Вам подойдет [B-tree](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114154/). Но можно и обычные многомерные, ассоциативные массивы.

P.S. Включите спеллчекер в браузере.

Comment: Проще есть варианты? ))

Мне php+mySql хватит с головой